# Rounding up with two decimal places usind SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rounding

I want to a number like 3.5212, becomes 3.53. But using:

```
select Ceiling(3.5212)
```

it returns 4.

Can I make it always round up with two decimal places?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to multiply the value by `100`  before `ceiling` function and then divide the final value by `100` as below.

```
select Ceiling(3.5212 * 100) / 100
```

**Result:**

```
VAL
--------
3.530000
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GGUBP47511)**